# Life was OR Life were

Tags: tenses, past-tense

Life was beautiful without the internet. 
OR
Life were beautiful without the internet.

which one is correct sentence? or sentence need some changes?

Should I consider 'life' as singular or plural ?

Comment: Either works. To a straight native speaker like me, who has simply an idiomatic understanding of English, "were" involves use of "the subjunctive". A linguistics professor, such as John Lawler, will say there is no such thing as "the subjunctive" in English. And he has a rather more technical way of describing what is going on.

Comment: Either _life was beautiful_ or _people's lives were beautiful_.

Comment: @KateBunting Subjunctive? *When I were young life was beautiful.* or *Life were beautiful, when I was young.*

Comment: Munaf, the sentence "Life were beautiful ..." is NOT a grammatically correct English sentence.  The answer from @KateBunting is correct.

Comment: @TechnoCat [Not nearly as plentiful as "Life was", but "Life were..." clearly exists.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Life+were%2C+Life+was&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CLife%20were%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CLife%20was%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: “If your life were a movie, which one would it be.”  The subjunctive needs something to call it into question. The  condition of irrealis must be present. “And were I not immortal, life were done between this heavenly and earthly sun.”

Comment: “And but thou love me, let them find me here: my life were better ended by their hate.” -Romeo M. And these are quite possibly just as apt counter-examples for why to avoid it.  It sounds odd, very odd. NB: “And but thou...” in this context means “If you don’t...” supplying the irrealis.

Comment: @WS2 Surely your example is nonstandard English, not the subjunctive? I would expect "Life were beautiful when I were young", probably said with a Yorkshire accent.

Comment: @KateBunting Well, one could certainly use the subjunctive to say e.g. "Oh, if only life were the way it was" or  "If life were beautiful here, we wouldn't object to the price of the hotel". And the corpus of Ngrams is the written word - so the examples can't simply have come from people with Yorkshire accents. So if the OP is saying they have seen "Life were beautiful..." in print, I believe them.

Comment: @WS2 Of  course I wasn't suggesting that using _were_ for the subjunctive was wrong, just that your examples didn't seem to be the subjunctive.

Comment: @KateBunting Maybe they're not. How about "If only life were beautiful, more would be persuaded to stay"?